# Error while contacting Elastic Beanstalk Service CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

Getting error when using eb deploy to an aws elastic beanstalk environment.

Error while contacting Elastic Beanstalk Service
ERROR: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.  As it turns out I had Fiddler running in the background which causes the SSL error.  Check to see if you have any proxies running.  If so turn them off and try again.